# Ideal and its number of generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Consider an ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]$ such that $I$ is generated by $x_1x_3, x_2x_3, x_1x_4,$ and $x_2x_4$. I think this ideal cannot be generated by two elements, but can't give a rigorous proof.

Can anyone suggest a proof?

Comment: The ideal generated by $x_1$ and $x_2$ contains all the listed elements.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. I will correct it.