# A question regarding the number of generators of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $I$ be an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1 ,x_2 ,x_3 ,x_4 ]$  such that $I$  is generated by $x_1 x_3$, $x_2 x_3$, $x_1 x_4$,  and $x_2 x_4$. How to show that this I cannot be generated by two elements?

It seems intuitively clear but, can't prove it rigorously

Comment: I guess you're taking the same class as [this person](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976655/ideals-and-the-number-of-generators)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Intuition that doesn't lead to the first few lines of a proof sounds more like "wishful thinking" than intuition, to me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $I$ contains no linear monomial, so the generating polynomials $p_i$ must be equal to $q_i+r_i$, where $q_i$ is a quadratic form and $r_i$ a sum of monomials of degree three or higher. Therefore, $x_1x_3$, $x_2x_3$, $x_1x_4$, and $x_2x_4$ are linear combinations of $q_i$'s, and so there are at least four $p_i$'s.